# Map<String, String> to TreeMap<Integer, String>

Tags: java, maps, treemap

I have a `Map<String, String>` object. I want to have it sorted by the keys, but the keys should be seen as integer. I just created an `TreeMap<Integer, String>(myMapObject)`.

But this obviously does not work. How can I create a new TreeMap and change the keys from String to Integer?

Comment: Please provide more example code... Do you have just a `Map<String, String>` or an object containing that structure? Can't you implement some POJO that `implements Comparable`?

Comment: which version of java do you use. and are these keys convertable to Integer ?

Comment: @deHaar OP has already given the map signatures. Its not POJO, just String and Integer classes. But yes as suggested use a simple comparator which convert String to Integer internally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Collectors.toMap` in Java 8:

```
Map<Integer, String> map1 = map.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> Integer.parseInt(entry.getKey()), Map.Entry::getValue, (a, b) -> b));
```

Or below traditional approach:

```
Map<Integer, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();

for(final Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()){
     map1.put(Integer.parseInt(entry.getKey()), entry.getValue());
}
```